# Python prim number t/f example

Tags: python, python-3.4

THIS IS NOT HOME WORK.

I am trying to learn Python. I am using cbt nuggets and the Python they use is 2.x I am using 3.x and my code does not work as typed the same at theirs. I tried to modify and it still does not work.

The example is to find prime numbers T/F.

```
num= 6 #a number greater than 2 
prime = True # a boolean to rember if this number is prime or not

for test in range(2,num):

    if num % test == 0 and num != test:
        print(num, 'equals ',test, '*' /test)
        prime = False

if prime:
    print(num, 'is a prime number!')
else:
    print(num, 'is not a prime number.')
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You would need to be more detailed than - *it still does not work.* - what does not work?

Comment: What is `'*' /test` supposed to do?  Is that actually in their code?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  What is happening?  Why?  Although, it looks like you have a syntax error in your code.

Comment: The only thing I changed was that I remove the    num/test as it kept giving an error invalid syntax.   I also changed the (2, 10) as they did in the video. The code is not mine.    It will work if I don't use (2,num) and used (2,10) however it still only would work if your used prim numbers.

Comment: This is the error I get when I try to run the code I originally posted above.        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Prime num True False loop.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(num, 'equals ',test, '*' /test)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 3):

this:

```
print(num, 'equals ',test, '*' /test)
```

should be:

```
print(num, 'equals ',test, '*', num//test)
```

Comment: I just tried to edit this and it does not work on python 3.4.3 not sure is that makes a difference. It highlights num and says invalid syntax.

Comment: Did you copy exactly what Raf said? If you missed the comma for example, you would get the syntax error you describe.

Comment: This did work I was missing the comma after '*',  Thank you all for your help. I really appreciate each of you taking time to help me out. I am slowly getting the hang of things.